# How to log in into the website https://www.flipkart.com/ with credentials

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I tried to log in into **Flipkart** website using python selenium.

the **code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('location to chrome driver')
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2zrpKA').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "{}"]'.format('password')).send_keys(Password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "{}")]'.format('login')).click()
```

code executed with `exit code 0 (No errors)`,  but not getting the dashboard page after login, login form popup is still visible.

Comment: Official docs say , you should not mix implicit wait with explicit wait , doing so can cause unpredictable time out

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of a couple of facts here as follows:

- To maximize the *Chrome Browser* instead of using `maximize_window()` always use an instance of **`ChromeOptions()`**.
- As the website `https://www.flipkart.com/` is based on [**ReactJS**](https://reactjs.org/) *WebDriverWait* is inevitable, so you need to remove all the instances of `implicitly_wait()` as documentation of [Explicit and Implicit Waits](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) mentions:

> Do not mix `implicit` and `explicit` *waits*. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.

- Remove the hardcoded `time.sleep()` as well.
- Before sending the `username` character sequence you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- Here is your own code implementing the above mentioned changes:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'Enter Email/Mobile number')]//preceding::input[1]"))).send_keys("siva")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Enter Password')]//preceding::input[1]").send_keys("narayana")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']//span[contains(.,'Login')]").click()
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: flipkart_login]

Answer (score 0):

Your login button `xPath` is not correct. This will work:

```
//button[@type = 'submit']/span
```

The full code would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('location to chrome driver')
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/')

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2zrpKA').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "{}"]'.format('password')).send_keys(Password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type = 'submit']/span").click()
```

Also instead of hard coded pause you can use `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('location to chrome driver')
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/')
driver.maximize_window()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "_2zrpKA"))).send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "{}"]'.format('password')).send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type = 'submit']/span").click()
```

this will be executed much more faster. More information can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: Official docs say , you should not mix implicit wait with explicit wait , doing so can cause unpredictable time out.

Comment: @cruisepandey nice catch! Forgot to remove. Thank you! already fixed

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov, Thank You it is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sivanarayana happy to hear it! If you are satisfied with the help you can mark one of the answers by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('location to chrome driver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")

username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[autocomplete] input[type='text']")
username.send_keys("username")

password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[autocomplete] input[type='password']")
password.send_keys("password")  

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Login']/ancestor::button")
login_button.click()
```

Make sure to import these :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

You may introduce explicit wait (webdriver wait). But for just login purpose, you do not need. But further if you are automating flipkart, IMO you should explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements available with Login as Text in the Modal box. your xpath is pointing to the first label Login. So, you need to modify your XPath as below

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button//span[contains(text(), "{}")]'.format('login')).click()
```

Your Xpath is pointing to the Red highlighted box .But expected Login is button which is highlighted in Green color.So, please just add the `//button` before your xpath

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Flipkart {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");

  WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

  driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");    

  driver.manage().window().maximize();

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_2zrpKA _1dBPDZ']")).sendKeys("naveen@gmail.com");

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_2zrpKA _3v41xv _1dBPDZ']")).sendKeys("Hahaha@9090");

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_2AkmmA _1LctnI _7UHT_c']")).click();

  Thread.sleep(300);
}
}
```